# How to keep selection of window.getSeleciton() when click input

Tags: input, vuejs3, selection, getselection

I'm write with vue3 [source code](https://github.com/vuluu2k/color-picker-vue3) but I cannot handle input remove selection text when click it

[Image description source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trQIE.png)

I'm try with mousedown.prevent but input not working
I'm try with savedSelection = window.getSelection(), then recovery it. But it not find for my project

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm trying to use input without affecting the highlighted area of ​​the mouse ( window.getSelecion() )